# Как сделать так, чтобы можно было отправлять HTTP POS запросы?

Tags: c#, wcf, service, веб-служба

Есть WCF-сервис, в нем есть метод "Start (string param)". Я его опубликовал на IIS, имею его  IP/Port, его УРЛ имеет вид

```
https://172.168.1.1:4400/Service.svc
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы можно было отправлять HTTP POS запросы? Можно ли использовать указанный выше УРЛ для этих целей?

Answer (score 2):

Для WCF способ один: [WebHttpBinding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275279/Developing-WCF-Restful-Services-with-GET-and-POST).

Есть другие варианты создания сервисов для работы с GET/POST запросами без WCF:

1. Использовать [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/create-a-web-api-with-mvc-6).
2. Хардкорный. Использовать HttpHadler в ASP.NET.

Если вам нужен REST-сервис, например, я бы порекомендовал использовать ASP.NET Web API.